# What security issues may have when Silverlight App in full screen mode?

Tags: silverlight, fullscreen

In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023(v=vs.95).aspx , What security issues may have if NOT disable events below?

> When a Silverlight-based application is in full-screen mode, most keyboard events are disabled. This limitation of keyboard input during full-screen mode is a **security feature**, and is intended to minimize the possibility of unintended information being entered by a user. In full-screen mode, the only input allowed is through the following keys:
>
> UP ARROW
>
> DOWN ARROW
>
> LEFT ARROW
>
> RIGHT ARROW
>
> SPACEBAR
>
> TAB
>
> PAGE UP
>
> PAGE DOWN
>
> HOME
>
> END
>
> ENTER

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you could do when running full screen is spoofing (immitating) a (windows) log-in box to gather user names and passwords.

By disabling all other keys (other than the ones listed) even when the log-in UI is spoofed the user will not be able to enter his credentials.

**EDIT**

BTW: you do not need to disable the listed events/keys because there are hardly any security issues involved with these keys. If there is such an issue chances are you will need to disable the mouse too because these keys are very comparable to what can be done by using the mouse.

Comment: Here's a thought. After a period of disuse, show a message like "Keyboard not detected. Enter password to scan for new hardware", along with a graphical display of a keyboard entry box where people can enter the username/password. Surely some non-trivial number of people would fall for it.

Comment: Seriously. I think a few people would fall for it. Maybe even enough for this to be an interesting social engineering attack.